# How to edit/replace an existing page when the ribbon is not visible?

Tags: 2010, search

I was just going to follow this tutorial
http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/01/create-a-content-type-search-refinement-panel-in-sharepoint-2010.html

They say this:
Edit the search results page, and modify the Refinement Panel web part
In the Refinement category modify the Filter Category Definition to include the following XML:

However in the current project, there is no ribbon so I cant edit the page,even if I am the site collection administrator, I suppose they hide it for any reason.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: How to do this step using a visual studio feature?

Comment: Is this using a custom master page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a **ToolPaneView=2** parameter in page url http://kb4sp.wordpress.com/2008/04/09/how-to-edit-a-page-that-has-no-edit-page-menu-option-in-wss-moss/

Comment: And then go to <root>/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx and navigate to the 'Pages' library and check in/publish the page.

Comment: cool, this was what I was looking for!!! worked inmediately!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find Edit Page option in Site Actions.
This changes your result page into Edit mode. 
For more details about result page refer this link..
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg576964.aspx