# How to deploy changes in one webpart fromd dev to test and production

Tags: 2010, deployment

Regarding this question here:
[How to edit/replace an existing page when the ribbon is not visible?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30013/how-to-edit-replace-an-existing-page-when-the-ribbon-is-not-visible)

lets say that in test I already have my configuration done.

New mapped property
Changed the refinement panel XML
and whatever other changes that need to be done to make that work.

Now I want to deploy that to test and prod? How can I do that? What options do I have?

Usually I do everything with Visual Studio solution packages, but in the above scenario I dont know if its possible to do those changes via visual studio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code for the webpart is the same between environments you could simply Export the web part to an .webpart file.  This file is just an XML file that contains all of the properties set on the that particular instance of the webpart. You could then upload that file to your other environments.  The Export option is on the edit menu for the web part.

If the code differs between environments then you really should deploy it as part of the WSP.

Comment: how can I deploy an existing webpart configuration as a WSP_?

Comment: This is for a manual deployment not a WSP, which was why I asked about the code.  I am pretty sure that it is possible to create a WSP that deploys just the .webpart file.